# How do I use thermald without intel_pstate?

Tags: ubuntu, fan, cooling

I have Ubuntu 14.10 and even with a cooling fan, it still gets hot. I have tried enabling intel_pstate but my system doesn't support it. How do I use thermald without intel_pstate?

Comment: What temperature are you considering to be "hot"? Does it reach that temperature even when idling? If the latter, then it might be that the thermal paste between the CPU and its heatsink needs replacing.

Comment: The tempature is good on Windows. But It;s bad on Ubuntu for some reason, even when idle.

Comment: It could be that you are getting a false temperature reading in Ubuntu - I assume you have used `top` or similar to confirm that it is idle. Otherwise, there are a lot of results if you search for "ubuntu cpu hot".